# PHP image upload and resize runs out of memory (96MB Memory Limit)

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading, image-upload

Im developing a website where users can upload multiple images to the server/website, in my upload script I have put an image size limit of 10MB.  This is because I thought a lot of modern cameras take large images.

The upload script takes each image, one at a  time, and resizes in to 3 different versions, 900x600, 600x450 and a smaller thumbnail image, and also puts a watermark image over the top of the 2 larger images.

I set my php.ini memory_limit to 96MB which I presumed would be easily enough.

After a bit of testing, I was uploading a jpg image which is 6.38MB in size and the resolution is 6143 x 3855 px in size.   I received the error message "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 100663296 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24572 bytes)"

Do you think it is reasonable to need this much memory to upload and process an image of this size?  or do you think it is more likely a problem with the coding in my script?

96 MB memory limit seems a lot to me.  What are other peoples experience dealing with large image uploads?  Should I set the memory limit to 128MB or higher?  or should I look at rewriting my upload script?

My Code is added below :

```
      //If a new image has been added, resize and upload to filesystem
      if ($_FILES['new_image']['name'] !=''){

          $allowed_types=array(
            'image/gif' => '.gif',
            'image/jpeg' => '.jpg',
            'image/png' => '.png',
            'image/x-png' => '.png',
            'image/pjpeg' => '.jpg'
          );

          $img = $_FILES['new_image'];

          // Check the file to be uploaded is the correct file type and is under 9MB              

          if ((array_key_exists($img['type'], $allowed_types)) && ($img['size'] < 9000000))              {
          // File to be uploaded is Valid


          // File to be uploaded is Valid

          $imagename = stripslashes($_FILES['new_image']['name']);

          // make the random file name
          $randName = md5(rand() * time());
          $ext = pathinfo($imagename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 


          $imagename = $randName . "." . $ext;
          $source = $_FILES['new_image']['tmp_name'];


          // Check if Directory Exists, if not create it
          if(!file_exists("images/breeds/".$trimmed['profile_id']))
          { 
               mkdir("images/breeds/".$trimmed['profile_id']) or die("Could not create images folder for article ".$trimmed['profile_id']);
          } 

          // Check if thumbnail Directory Exists
          if(!file_exists("images/breeds/".$trimmed['profile_id']."/thumbs")) 
          { 
              mkdir("images/breeds/".$trimmed['profile_id']."/thumbs") or die("Could not create thumbnail folder for article ".$trimmed['profile_id']);
          } 

          // Check if thumbnail Directory Exists
          if(!file_exists("images/breeds/".$trimmed['profile_id']."/large")) 
          { 
              mkdir("images/breeds/".$trimmed['profile_id']."/large") or die("Could not create thumbnail folder for article ".$trimmed['profile_id']);
          } 


          $LargeImage = "images/breeds/".$trimmed['profile_id']."/large/".$imagename;
          $NormalImage = "images/breeds/".$trimmed['profile_id']."/".$imagename;
          $SmallImage = "images/breeds/".$trimmed['profile_id']."/thumbs/".$imagename;

          //uploaded temp file
          $file = $_FILES['new_image']['tmp_name'];


          //Get Image size info
          list($width, $height, $image_type) = getimagesize($file);

          //SourceImage
          switch ($image_type) 
          {
            case 1: $image = imagecreatefromgif($file); break;
            case 2: $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);  break;
            case 3: $image = imagecreatefrompng($file); break;
            default:  trigger_error('Unsupported filetype!', E_USER_WARNING);  break;
          }


          // Constraints for Large Image 
          $max_width = 900; 
          $max_height = 600; 
          $ratioh = $max_height/$height; 
          $ratiow = $max_width/$width; 
          $ratio = min($ratioh, $ratiow); 

          if (($height < $max_height) && ($width < $max_width)) {
           //keep same dimensions
           $modwidth = $width;
           $modheight = $height;
          } else {
          // New dimensions 
          $modwidth = intval($ratio*$width); 
          $modheight = intval($ratio*$height);
          }

          $tmpLarge = imagecreatetruecolor( $modwidth, $modheight );

          imagecopyresampled($tmpLarge, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height) ; 

          // Add Watermark to large image at top right

          $wm = "images/p4h-wm-200.png";
          $wmImage = imagecreatefrompng($wm); 
          $wmW = imagesx($wmImage); 
          $wmH = imagesy($wmImage); 

          $photoW = imagesx($tmpLarge); 
          $photoH = imagesy($tmpLarge);
          $dest_x = $photoW - $wmW - 10; 
          $dest_y = 10;

          // imagecopymerge($tn, $wmImage, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $wmW, $wmH, 100); 
          imagecopy($tmpLarge, $wmImage, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $wmW, $wmH);


          switch ($image_type) 
          {
             case 1: imagegif($tmpLarge,$LargeImage); break;
             case 2: imagejpeg($tmpLarge,$LargeImage, 80);  break;
             case 3: imagepng($tmpLarge,$LargeImage, 0); break;
             default:  trigger_error('Failed resize image!', E_USER_WARNING);  break;
          }


          // Destroy tmp images to free memory
          imagedestroy($tmpLarge);
          imagedestroy($wmImage);


          // Constraints for Normal Image 
          $max_width = 550; 
          $max_height = 413; 
          $ratioh = $max_height/$height; 
          $ratiow = $max_width/$width; 
          $ratio = min($ratioh, $ratiow); 

          if (($height < $max_height) && ($width < $max_width)) {
           //keep same dimensions
           $modwidth = $width;
           $modheight = $height;
          } else {
          // New dimensions 
          $modwidth = intval($ratio*$width); 
          $modheight = intval($ratio*$height);
          }

          $tmpNormal = imagecreatetruecolor( $modwidth, $modheight );

          imagecopyresampled($tmpNormal, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height) ; 

          // Add Watermark to large image at top right

          $wm = "images/p4h-wm-150.png";
          $wmImage = imagecreatefrompng($wm); 
          $wmW = imagesx($wmImage); 
          $wmH = imagesy($wmImage); 

          $photoW = imagesx($tmpNormal); 
          $photoH = imagesy($tmpNormal);
          $dest_x = $photoW - $wmW - 10; 
          $dest_y = 10;

          // imagecopymerge($tn, $wmImage, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $wmW, $wmH, 100); 
          imagecopy($tmpNormal, $wmImage, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $wmW, $wmH);

          switch ($image_type) 
          {
             case 1: imagegif($tmpNormal,$NormalImage); break;
             case 2: imagejpeg($tmpNormal,$NormalImage, 90);  break;
             case 3: imagepng($tmpNormal,$NormalImage, 0); break;
             default:  trigger_error('Failed resize image!', E_USER_WARNING);  break;
          }

          // Destroy tmp images to free memory
          imagedestroy($tmpNormal);
          imagedestroy($wmImage);


          // Now that the full size image has been saved, resize the thumbnail one to a fixed size for homepage display
          // Constraints 
          $thumb_width = 150; 
          $thumb_height = 112.5; 

         // Calculate stuff and resize image accordingly     
         $src_ratio = $width/$height;
         $dst_ratio = $thumb_width/$thumb_height;
         if($src_ratio < $dst_ratio) // trim top and bottom
         {
            $ratio = $width/$thumb_width;
            $crop_height = $thumb_height*$ratio;
            $src_y = round(($height-$crop_height)/2);
            $crop_width = $width;
            $src_x = 0;
         }
         else // trim left and right
         {
            $ratio = $height/$thumb_height;
            $crop_width = $thumb_width*$ratio;
            $src_x = round(($width-$crop_width)/2);
            $crop_height = $height;
            $src_y = 0;
         }


          $tmpSmall = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );

          imagecopyresampled($tmpSmall, $image, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $crop_width, $crop_height);

          switch ($image_type) 
          {
             case 1: imagegif($tmpSmall,$SmallImage); break;
             case 2: imagejpeg($tmpSmall,$SmallImage, 90);  break;
             case 3: imagepng($tmpSmall,$SmallImage, 0); break;
             default:  trigger_error('Failed resize image!', E_USER_WARNING);  break;
          }

        // Destroy images to free memory
        imagedestroy($image);
        imagedestroy($tmpSmall);
```

Comment: are you destroying/releasing the images after you are done with them? Are you holding open 4 images at once, or creating, saving and destroying each serially?

Comment: Posting the codes might help. Also which library/tools are you using to resize the images?

Comment: Please see my code added above

Answer (score 0):

jpg is 6.38MB , but to transform image, the internal representation used is the raw uncompressed one.

your image is 23.6 Mega Pixel

the uncompressed representation of it could be 32bit (4Bytes) per pixel, ie : 4*23.6MBytes = 94 MBytes.

So, i would say, do you need to have such big images to process ?

if yes, put memory_limit higher
if no , limit the uploadable image size to something more reasonable to process within your memory settings.

Comment: The website is a classifieds website where people will be uploading images to their adverts.  I want to make sure that I allow images of a reasonable size to be uploaded.  Overwise it would be annoying if everytime someone tried to upload an image it  ame back saying it was too big.

Comment: so, in that case, i would suggest to put php memory limit at least around 256MB and to perform a quick calculation on your upload script before trying to process the image in case it is really too big.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to give more hints to PHP on when the memory can be released. A simple `$some_variable = null;` is usually enough.

Once you're finished with an image (the main image and each of its thumbnails), set the referencing variable to `null` to help free up memory.

Otherwise, try printing out or logging the results of `memory_get_usage()` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) at the top of your script and in various places throughout your script to track down where memory is getting bogged down.

Comment: I use imagedestroy()  for releasing memory when I have finished with the images, please see my code above which I have added.

Answer (score 0):

A 6143x3855 image will require **AT LEAST** 71,043,795 bytes of memory just for the raw pixel data (3 bytes per pixel). Then you create a series of other images to hold resized versions of the original, etc...

No wonder you're running out of memory.

Comment: Looks like my script is probably ok then, and I just need to increase my memory limit to 256MB maybe.